# Call method when input text is changed

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular2-forms, materialize

I'm using Angular 5 with Materialize and I have a datepicker who works perfectly:

```
<input materialize="pickadate" 
 type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="Selecione a Data" 
 [materializeParams]=datePickerParams>
```

I want to call a method like "dateChanged(date)" when this input date is changed, I've tried using (change)="dateChanged($event)" for instance, but isn't working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use **`ngModel`** with **`ngModelChange`**

```
<input materialize="pickadate"  [ngModel]="date"
 (ngModelChange)="onKey($event)" type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="Selecione a Data" [materializeParams]=datePickerParams>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not an angular expert too, I'm learning.
If you use Reactive Form, you can use something like

```
this.form.get('date').valueChanges.subscribe(date => {
  // do what you want
  // Tue Apr 03 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)
  // you can use date.getTime()
})
```

You just need to set formControlName in date input!
I`d recommend to use reactive form!
Can you try and tell me if its worked?
Thanks and sorry for my knowlegde and english!

Comment: IMHO this should be the accepted answer. Reactive forms is the way to go.